# How to reset permissions to "control iTunes"?

Tags: mojave, music.app, macos

TL;DR: If an app asks permission to “control iTunes” (in MacOS 10.14), and the user denies it, how can this be reversed?

I can’t find anything in System Preferences nor Music preferences to reverse the denial of control.

Background: Have a really crappy app from IonAudio.com which crashes before getting past step two.  What triggers this is apparently some setting inside the app’s bundle created by force quit.  Had to force quit because when it asked permission to control iTunes, I inadvertently hit No.  That puts it in an infinite loop of modal pop ups saying “writing audio file failed, try again?”  Each has only a Retry button, no way out.  To run the app again, I have to delete it, reboot, and reinstall.  I can digitize ONE cassette, pull the file from /tmp then force quit, reboot, etc.  Chronic proctalgia.

Comment: Please don’t claim it is unclear without being clear about what you don’t understand.

Comment: Does this not answer your question? -- From [Allow accessibility apps to access your Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/allow-accessibility-apps-to-access-your-mac-mh43185/10.14/mac/10.14) "Denied apps are listed in the Accessibility section of the Privacy pane. If you later decide to give a denied app access to your Mac, choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, click Privacy, click Accessibility, then select the app’s checkbox."

Comment: If not, have a look at: [How to reset a user's privacy permissions on macOS and iOS](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-reset-a-users-privacy-permissions-on-macos-and-ios/)

Comment: One website said it was in Privacy. Another said it was in accessibility.  And a third said it was in User:Login Items: advanced.  All false, at least for 10.14.6.  I will try tccutil

Comment: Tccutil did the job; perhaps make it the answer.  The IonAudio app is still crap, but when it doesn’t crash, I get a file I can work with.

Comment: Did you remove it by `name` or `bundle id`, or did you have to use `all`?

Comment: Just said “all” because I didn’t know whether the name would much the stupid file name of the app.